# Cofinal ultrafilters are non-principal?

Tags: order-theory, filters

The definitions that I am using are:
:
A cofinal ultrafilter $\mathcal {U} $ on a directed set $I $ is an ultrafilter which contains the cofinal filter base, i.e. family of all subsets of the form $\{i\in I: i\geq i_0\} $.

I thought that it is non principal or contains no finite sets at least in the case that $I $ is infinite. However, I succeded to do so just under the assumption that there is no $y\in I $ such that $y\geq x $ for all $x\in I $.

Comment: Well as you noticed it isn't non principal in all cases : take $I=\omega+1$ for instance, the cofinal filter base contains $\{\omega\}$ and so $\mathcal{U}$ would contain it, making it principal. Additional assumption must be made for it to be true, for instance the one you mention at the end of your question

Comment: For the converse, if $y\in I$ and $y\geq x$ for all $x\in I$ then $\{S\subset I: y\in S\}$ is a principal ultrafilter that contains every member of the cofinal filter base.